# How do I share a project and files across macOS and PC?

Tags: windows, macos, sync, path, camtasia

I use Camtasia for video editing. I keep the recorded video files on Google Drive. Google Drive syncs the files across both computers without any issue. However, the files end up in different paths for the two operating systems. The Camtasia project file tscproj is a JSON file that points to the recorded video. However, it stores the absolute paths - not the relative paths. So, the project is going to be different on both computers. More importantly, it is completely different on the video editor's computer.

Most people work around this by exporting the project to a zip file and then unzipping it on the other side. This leads to countless problems and changes don't show up immediately on the other side.

I've considered using symbolic links to the folders. This might work but I was hoping there is an easier way. Please throw some ideas at me.

Comment: Even using symbolic links, one machine would have C:\folder\project\ & the other  /Volumes/diskName/folder/project/

Comment: Yes. You are right. It turns out though that the app will look in the folder of the project for the file so as long as all the files are there it will work. I ended up solving the problem by storing all the files in Git with Git LFS instead of Google Drive. This really isn't a full answer though because this won't for all apps where the problem is the same.